# Lambda functions with Optional instead of nested if else

Tags: java, lambda, option-type

```java
Optional<String> myData;
Set<String> mySet;
if(myData.isPresent()) {
    if(myData.get().contains(“testValue”)) {
        mySet.add(“somedata”);
    }
}
if(!myData.isPresent()) {
    mySet.add(“someotherdata”);
}
```

I have a scenario like this. Where I have nested if-else block and I need to convert that into Java8 map using lambda functions. How can I do that?

Comment: Q: Why do you need to "convert" anything?  ALSO: Are you sure you've got all the conditions?  Do you need to do anything else if myData.isPresent() && !myData.get().contains("testValue")?

Comment: What do you do to the `Set` if data is present but it doesn't equal "testValue"?

Comment: You can replace `if(!myData.isPresent())` with `else`. Besides that, it would be good to respond to the questions in the previous comments.

Comment: Convert into a map of what to what? `Optional` has a `.map()` method, is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You could rework your `Optional` use (this only apply to your code, as originally presented [in case you edit it]):

```
Optional<String> myData = ...;
myData.ifPresent(value -> {
  if (value.contains("testValue")) {
    mySet.add("somedata"),
  }
});
if (!myData.isPresent()) {
  mySet.add("someotherdata");
}
```

If you are using Java 11, you should use:

```
myData.ifPresentOrElse(
         value -> {
           if (value.contains("testValue")) {
             mySet.add("somedata");
           }
         }, 
         () -> mySet.add("someotherdata")
      );
```

It is up to you to decide which is better (the first avoid doing `mySet.add` twice in two part).

[edit] fixed the answer and compilation issues per comment remark.

Answer (score 1):

This will reproduce your earlier results but has been slightly altered. I believe that a stream solution is not necessary nor desirable. The following will:

- result in an `empty set` if data is present but not `testValue`
- result in the set containing `someotherdata` if the data is not present
- result in the set containing `somedata` if the data is present and matches `testValue`

```
String result = myData.isPresent() ?
        (myData.get().contains("testValue") ? "somedata" : "") :
        "someotherdata";

if (!result.isBlank()) {
    mySet.add(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` to avoid the nested logic in the present case. Your second case has no nested logic, seems fine as is.

```
myData.filter(d -> d.contains("testValue"))
  .ifPresent(mySet::add);

if(!myData.isPresent()) {
    mySet.add(“someotherdata”);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you insist:

```
    Optional<String> myData = Optional.of("x");
    Set<String> mySet = myData
            .<Set<String>>map(s -> s.contains("testValue") ? Set.of("somedata") : Set.of())
            .orElse(Set.of("someotherdata"));
    System.out.println(mySet);
```

Output in this case:

> []

Testing other optionals:

```
    Optional<String> myData = Optional.of("x testValue x");
```

> [somedata]

```
    Optional<String> myData = Optional.empty();
```

> [someotherdata]

My own preference is for the use of `ifPresentOrElse()` shown in the last half of the answer by NoDataFound.